# Configuring connectors for multiple topics on Kafka Connect Distributed Mode

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have producers that are sending the following to Kafka:

- topic=syslog, ~25,000 events per day
- topic=nginx, ~5,000 events per day
- topic=zeek.xxx.log, ~100,000 events per day (total). In this last case there are 20 distinct zeek topics, such as zeek.conn.log and zeek.http.log

`kafka-connect-elasticsearch` instances function as consumers to ship data from Kafka to Elasticsearch. The hello-world Sink configuration for [`kafka-connect-elasticsearch`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) might look like this:

```
# elasticsearch.properties
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=24
topics=syslog,nginx,zeek.broker.log,zeek.capture_loss.log,zeek.conn.log,zeek.dhcp.log,zeek.dns.log,zeek.files.log,zeek.http.log,zeek.known_services.log,zeek.loaded_scripts.log,zeek.notice.log,zeek.ntp.log,zeek.packet_filtering.log,zeek.software.log,zeek.ssh.log,zeek.ssl.log,zeek.status.log,zeek.stderr.log,zeek.stdout.log,zeek.weird.log,zeek.x509.log
topic.creation.enable=true
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
...
```

And can be invoked with `bin/connect-standalone.sh`. I realized that running or attempting to run `tasks.max=24` when work is performed in a single process is not ideal. I know that using distributed mode would be a better alternative, but am unclear on the performance-optimal way to submit connectors to distributed mode. Namely,

- **In distributed mode, would I still want to submit just a single `elasticsearch.properties` through a single API call? Or would it be best to break up multiple `.properties` configs + connectors (e.g. one for syslog, one for nginx, one for zeek.**) and submit them separately?**
- I understand that `tasks` be equal to the number of topics x number of partitions, but what dictates the number of workers?
- Is there anywhere in the documentation that walks through best practices for a situation such as this where there is a noticeable imbalance of throughput for different topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In distributed mode, would I still want to submit just a single elasticsearch.properties through a single API call?

It'd be a JSON file, but yes.

> what dictates the number of workers?

Up to you. JVM usage is one factor that you can monitor and scale on

Not really any documentation that I am aware of

Comment: I suppose I'm confused by what exactly a worker is then. I get that a task is effectively a thread, but would submitting one JSON properties file equal one worker?

Comment: Edit of above comment: my understanding is I would run something akin to `bin/connect-distributed.sh worker.properties` on multiple nodes while specifying the same `group.id`. I'm assuming each of those is a worker process, and then would make a _single_ REST API request with the connector properties. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. You could also use Kubernetes, for example to launch multiple pods of some Connect image to run a cluster, then expose a load balancer for the API